# Determining if a graph is planar and if so draw or disprove with Kuratowski's Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

This is a practice exercise for in my text that even my professor was having trouble explaining to me. The instructions are in the title.

Here is an image of the graph:
[image]

I believe this graph is not planar. My professor stated that it was impossible to know a graph is not planar unless you can find the subgraph K5 or K3,3. I think I can collapse g and c, but I still don't think that will give me the correct graph. Is there something I am missing or is it just planar?

Answer (score 4):

Vertices $b,c,f$ are all adjacent to $a,d,e$ except for $c$ to $a$, for which you can go via $g$, and $c$ to $d$, for which go via $h$.  So the graph contains a subgraph which is *homeomorphic to* (I think this is the same as what you mean by "can be collapsed to") $K_{3,3}$, and so the graph is not planar.

If I was any good at posting diagrams this would be more clear, but I'm sure you can manage the diagrams for yourself.

Comment: When you say "go via g" and "which can go via h", do you mean I can reduce the edges c to d and c to a?

Comment: Sorry, bit hard to explain without a diagram.  I mean you have edges from $c$ to $g$ and $g$ to $a$; then you can remove the unwanted edge $gh$; then $g$ has degree $2$ so you can replace $cg$ and $ga$ by a single edge $ca$.  I think this last bit is probably what you mean by "collapse", though I have never actually heard this term myself.

Comment: Proof is a tiny bit simpler if you use $h$ instead of $c$; then the only thing you need is $h$ to $a$ via $g$.