# Trouble determining planarity of graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

I am practicing for an exam and I can not wrap my head around this exercise. I am supposed to show if the given graph is planar by drawing it or show the subgraph that is homeopathic to K <sub>3,3</sub> or K<sub>5</sub>.

The graph in question
[image: The graph in question]

I believe it is non-planar and can be reduced to K<sub>5</sub> but besides eliminating e(h,e) I can't find the rest of the edges to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

Vertices $b,c,d$ are all adjacent to $a,f,g$ except for $c$ to $a$, for which you can go via $i$, and $g$ to $d$, for which go via $h$ and $e$.  So the graph contains a subgraph which is *homeomorphic to* $K_{3,3}$, and so the graph is not planar.

See also my answer to [this very similar recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848936).

**Edit**.  In fact, the vertices $a,d,e,h,i$ are all adjacent except for $d,h$ where we can go via $b$ and $g$, and $d,i$ where we can go via $f$ and $c$.  So there is also a subgraph homeomorphic to $K_5$.

Comment: I see I was trying to find the wrong graph. Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily - there might be a $K_5$ subgraph as well, I didn't check.

Comment: In fact there is also a $K_5$, see updated answer.